# how to select usedrange column's data without header only in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to fetch a single column's data only with .usedrange using the below code but throws error

```
cU1 = nsh.UsedRange.ListObject.ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange
```

I also tried by finding the last row but when the last row equals the starting row it throws an error suppose in the below code when lastrow = 2

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = nsh.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
cU1=Range("I2:I" & lastrow)
```

I need the range of column"I" row values without the header

PS. The data doesn't have a table on it.

Comment: Just use a reference to the table: `nsh.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange`.

Comment: I haven't inserted a table on the data . I need to find without inserting a table

Comment: *"I need the range of column"I" row values without the header"* > What is `cU1`? If a `Range` object, you'll need to `Set` it. Also, if you don't have a table, why use a reference to `ListObjects`? And, what error are you talking about, and on what line?

Comment: If you don't have a table (`ListObject`), then why are you trying to use properties of a table?

Comment: cU1 is a variant

Comment: @BigBen that is where I am stuck with. I need the correct syntax to refer the datarange of an usedrange column

Comment: Change `Integer` to `Long`. Then please explain what the error message is for the second code snippet. `Range("I2:I2")` is perfectly valid so we need more detail.

Comment: Maybe cU1=Range("I2:I" & lastrow + 1)

Comment: @BigBen run time error type mismatch. when the lastrow > 2  the code works perfectly fine ,but when lastrow equals 2 its throwing this error i don't know why

Comment: That line throws a `Type Mismatch` error? Maybe show us more of your code.

Comment: You need to post more code.

Comment: sendBCC = ""  
    Set dU1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = nsh.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
    cU1 = Range("I2:I" & Lastrow)
    
    For iU1 = 1 To UBound(cU1, 1)
        dU1(cU1(iU1, 1)) = 1
    Next iU1
    Dim myarray() As String
    ReDim myarray(dU1.Count - 1)
    For i = 0 To dU1.Count - 1
      myarray(i) = "m" & dU1.keys()(i)
    Next i
    For i = 0 To dU1.Count - 1
        sendBCC = sendBCC & "; " & myarray(i)  'emailCell.Text
    Next

Comment: the above code is in a loop it works perfectly fine for the sheets which has lastrow more than 2 but when the lastrow is equal to 2 it shows type mismatch error on that line

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code, instead of posting in a comment, thanks.

Comment: Reading a single cell's value doesn't result in a variant array, it's a special case: see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link mate @BigBen. the special case worked just fine.